# Centralize Laravel Models and Migrations to be consumed by multiple Laravel API projects

Tags: c#, laravel

**I am wondering if it is possible to create a centralized model/migration in Laravel to be consumed by other Laravel API projects.**

For instance in C#, you can create a library that handles the data models and migration which can be reference to multiple API Core projects. By doing this, once I updated the library, all the project referenced to it will be updated. `If I'm not mistaken, it does work because the .dll contains all the models just like creating models for each C# API project if you don't have the .dlls.`

**What do I want and Why?**

I am planning to create multiple Laravel API project to implement CQRS and create a separate notification service. All this projects will have the same model and migrations.

Is there any similar solutions to centralized or ease the handling of all the data model and migrations in Laravel?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could build out the models and migrations in a composer package as described at https://laravel.com/docs/master/packages. Having access to them would then we as simple as adding them to the project.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages.md has some information on using vcs to add private repos to projects via composer.

Comment: I was thinking of the same thing but not sure if it is the right way since it is hard to find references on the web. Thank you for confirming. I'll try it and find out. :)